# Create WordPress page with custom fields using Node.js

Tags: node.js, wordpress

I'm been trying creating WordPress page with custom fields. The code below just adding a custom field but in a wrong way. Field Name is y and the value too.

```
    client.newPost({
    type: "page", 
    title: "a Page from Node.js", 
        content: "This page was created sending remotely post from 
    Node.js.....",
        status: "publish",
        pagetemplate: "template1.php",
        customFields: {
            "test":"yes"
        },
   }, function( error, data ) {
    console.log( "Post sent! The server replied with the following:\n" );
    console.log( arguments );
    console.log("\n");
});
```

I tried with: custom_fields, customFields, fields

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
client.newPost({
    type: "page", 
    title: "a Page from Node.js", 
        content: "This page was created sending remotely post from 
    Node.js.....",
        status: "publish",
        pagetemplate: "template1.php",
        customFields: [
            { key: "test", value: "yes" }
        ],
   }, function( error, data ) {
    console.log( "Post sent! The server replied with the following:\n" );
    console.log( arguments );
    console.log("\n");
});
```

---

Correct format for Custom Fields is:

```
customFields: [
    { key: "test", value: "yes" }
]
```

instead of:

```
customFields: {
    "test":"yes"
}
```

Tested locally with:

- WordPress 4.9.8
- node-wordpress 1.4.1